# How to change android device name used by NsdManager?

Tags: android, mdns, dns-sd

I am using NsdManager to register a web service on the local network. My problem is that the device name is called "android", so I can access the phone as "android.local" from my laptop. How can I change that name? I would like something more unique.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this (on non-rooted devices). "android" is the host name of the device, ".local" is the suffix added by the mDNS (see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)).