# How to change Android Things mDNS hostname (Android.local) to something else

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, adb, android-things, mdns

I have an IoT project that has to identify my **RaspberryPI** (which has **Android Things** OS) over the local network.

A good way to do this is by using the **Multicast DNS** (mDNS) that Android Things broadcasts as `Android.local`.

The question is: can I change the `Android.local` to `somethingelse.local` so that I dont have any conflicts ?

I know it is possible using a Linux OS, as showed [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/167190/how-and-why-to-assign-the-.local-domain-to-your-raspberry-pi/). Can I do the same on Android Things ?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796841/how-to-change-android-device-name-used-by-nsdmanager

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks for replying! Even though the question is similar, it is related to Android phones. My doubt is on Android Things OS running on RaspberryPI, which might give us more possibilities.

Comment: Would look here for APIs https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0 and things not supported: https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0-changes#top_of_page

Answer (score 1):

I know Android Things is no longer supported but still... I found solution:
You can set hostname over ADB:

```
adb connect x.x.x.x  # where x.x.x.x is ip address of your device                                                   
adb root
adb remount
adb shell
su
cd system
echo 'net.hostname=newHostName' >> build.prop
```

`echo 'net.hostname=newHostName' >> build.prop`  appends new line to build.prop file.. if you wish to rename again you need to remove this line before